# Why Collections.sort (dateList,Collections.reverseOrder()) is throwing NPE

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-8

When i am trying this :

```
if (serviceEndDateList != null && !serviceEndDateList.isEmpty()) {
    LOG.info("serviceEndDateList::"+serviceStartDateList);
    Collections.sort(serviceEndDateList, 
    Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

I am getting below stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator.compare(Collections.java:5117)[:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator.compare(Collections.java:5108)[:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)[:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)[:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)[:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)[:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)[:1.8.0_181]
```

The output of the log is :

```
serviceEndDateList::[2001-05-17]
serviceEndDateList::[2001-05-17, 2001-05-17]
```

As the object is not null why this Exception is being Thrown!!

Comment: Does your *list* contain a `null` value?

Comment: atleast the output doesn't say that!

Comment: But you are logging `serviceStartDateList` (**start**), not `serviceEndDateList` (**End**).

Comment: What are the elements in that list? Strings, or some other composite type? Maybe there's an NPE in the compare method? However, the stacktrace and the line very much suggests that indeed one of the elements is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your input list `serviceEndDateList` contains with the highest probability a `null` value that causes trouble in comparison.

You have to define, whether the `null` values will be included at the beginning or the end of a collection. Use the special wrapper for this case that pushes all the `null` values to the end:

```
Collections.sort(serviceEndDateList, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

From the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) JavaDoc (emphesizes mine):

- [`Comparator::nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) is a comparator that considers `null` to be **less** than non-null, and compares non-null objects with the supplied `Comparator`.
- [`Comparator::nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) is a comparator that considers `null` to be **greater** than non-null, and compares non-null objects with the supplied `Comparator`.